# Make fixed positioned div inherit width of parent instead of body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a sticky header on my HTML page where when the user scroll downs the header sticks to the top of the page.

I have implemented the sticky header functionality but I am facing a problem that when the div class="header-content" becomes fixed at the top of the page it overflows the width of the container it is in and tries to take the width of the whole 'body'. I want this sticky header to be 100% of its container's width.

My HTML is here:

```
<div class="container">
    <header id="header" role="banner">
            <div class="search">
                <form id="searchForm" action="#" method="get">
                    <input class="form-control search-input" name="q" id="q" placeholder="Search..." type="text" required />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
                    </span>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="header-content">
                <ul class="social-icons">
                    <li>List Item</li>  
                    <li>List Item</li>  
                    <li>List Item</li>  
                    <li>List Item</li>
                 </ul>

                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>Sample Logo</h1>
                </div>

            </div><!-- end header-content -->   
        </header><!-- end header -->

       <div id="main">
           <h2>Heading Goes Here</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
           <h3>Second Heading Goes Here</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
           <h2>Heading Goes Here</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
           <h3>Second Heading Goes Here</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>

       </div><!-- end main -->

</div><!-- end container -->
```

The CSS:

```
.container {width: 600px; margin: auto; background: #eee;} 
#header {width: 100%;}
.header-content {width: 100%; z-index: 400;}
.sticky {position: fixed; top: 0; transition: all 0.4s ease; background: red;}
```

The jQuery for the sticky header:

```
     $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30){  
            $('.header-content').addClass("sticky");
          }
          else{
            $('.header-content').removeClass("sticky");
          }
      });
```

I also made a JSFiddle so you can see this issue in real-time. You can view it here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/eng94871/

Notice that when you scroll down and the header is sticky at the top(the div with the red background) it overflows its container (the div with the gray background). I want to force it to have 100% width of the gray background.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `position: fixed` elements are not in the usual document flow, and so their width is taken to be 100% of the window. You can fix this by specifying the same `width` property on the element as on `.container`. Also note that you would need to change `transition: all` to `transition: background-color` otherwise the width is animated, which I don't believe is the effect you're after. Try this:

```
.sticky {
    width: 600px;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
    /* other properties... *.
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eng94871/1/)

Comment: i will need this 'sticky' to be responsive so i cannot give it a fixed width. Maybe there is a way to do this using jquery that jQuery would grab the width of the '.container' and set '.sticky'"s width as that?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `.sticky` `width` to `calc(100%)` , which should be 100% of `sticky` parent `#header` element

jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/eng94871/5/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting containers to one width:

```
.container, .sticky, .header-content {
     width: 600px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L7j8uj4/)